# Java grant codebase

Tags: java

I currently have a permission in Java Security Manager I want to grant to a specific codebase. However, this file exists in multiple locations.

For example:

```
/home/servers/1/code.jar
/home/servers/2/code.jar
/home/servers/3/code.jar
```

So far, I have tried:

```
grant codeBase "file:/home/servers/*/code.jar" {...
```

But that does not seem to work properly.

Comment: Which of those copies of code.jar do you actually run?

Comment: All of them are run, each is run by a different user.

Comment: You seem to have a rather unusual architecture here. I think before anybody can help, you need to document in much more detail what you are running and how, e.g. are different users running different processes? Invoked how? Or are they all part of the same app server process, dynamically loaded? If so, how?

Comment: Users will be running the jar files through a web control UI, each jar file will be a separate process. There will be more than just code.jar though, there may be for example code2.jar, which requires a different set of permissions than code.jar. Another way I have though of doing this is by using signing, as code.jar is the exact same in every location. However, I'm not familiar with how signing the jar file would work etc.